# How to fill an array from server answer with async pipes

Tags: sql-server, angular, asp.net-core

I'm new to Angular, and not so new to ASP.NET Core. I'm trying to retrieve data from backend server (ASP.NET Core & SQL Server Express & Dapper ORM). GET request passing valid ([first screen][1]), and now I want to map data from it to HTML view.

So a valid JSON is returned, and I'm trying to pass its values via async pipe. Correct ([second screen][2]). Then why can't I fill an array from other services and other GETs like on [third screen][3] and map them to array too like on [fourth screen][4]?

They're undefined when I'm trying to retrieve data from them like [that][5]. What's the problem and what RxJS expression do I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The async pipe will only work on observable sources. The GET request produces an observable, so async works.

If your other services are returning arrays (not arrays wrapped in an observable), async won't work and isn't necessary, anyway.

E.g.

```
const directArray: string[] = ["this", "that", "other"];
you can use *ngFor="let thing of directarray"

const observableArray: Subject<string[]> = new Subject();
observableArray.next(["this", "that", "other"]);
you can use *ngFor="let thing of observableArray | async"
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Other services are returning Observable<object> too, so i just need to "fill" an array wrapped by Observable and pass it to *ngFor. Problem is, i don't know how to do is with RxJS

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the issue. Are you concerned that you're seeing undefined in the console.log statements?  if so, you're getting that because you're trying to see data synchronously from an asynchronous source.  instead of the console.logs where they are, add .pipe(tap(s => console.log(s))) to the end of each of the service calls to see the data as it's resolved

Comment: Like so. departmentService.getDepartments() executes a GET request on the URL, returning an Observable of JSON object. Then, i do .pipe(tap(data => { console.log(data);})); but in console i see undefined. But when i'm trying to GET via Postman it return a valid JSON of {
        "departmentID": 1,
        "name": "Name",
        "floor": 4,
        "employees": null
    }, maybe the key to solution is near, but i'm kinda new to RxJS and Angular.
 
Code after changes:
this.departmentsService.getDepartments().pipe(tap(data=>{
      console.log(data);
    }));

Comment: E.g. this.employee$ = this.employeeService.getEmployees().pipe(tap(data => console.log("employees", data)));   you'll only see the data AFTER the template loads the observable using the async pipe.

Comment: wow. this explained so much :) thanks

Comment: just one question to get the full picture - i'll see the data ONLY when DOM renderer reaches my *ngFor|async statement where data i need is used?

Comment: right.  observables are, by nature, asynchronous.  That means that until something subscribes to them, they won't execute.  That's why you get undefined with console.log(this.employees$). I.E. you were console logging an unsubscribed observable, so there's nothing to show.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern